# Phonegap Zbar iTunes Connect Invalid Bundle Structure

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect, zbar

I am using Zbar phonegap plugin for iOS. When I am trying to upload my ipa file to iTunes connect it gives an error saying "Invalid Bundle Structure" since zbar plugin has libzbar.a library.

I am using following tag in plugin.xml to refer the zbar library.

Following is the exact error I am getting from iTunes.
ERROR ITMS-90171:"Invalid Bundle Structure- The binary file '.../libzbar.a' is not permitted. Your app can't contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles.